# how to add a dollar sign to a long object in python

Tags: python, printing, string-formatting

Im tring to add a dollar sign to this print statement in front of row[2]:

```
print row[0], row[1], row[2]
```

the figure should print out with no space like: `$1000`
 it cannot be `$ 1000`

can anyone help?

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: im importing the rows from an MySQL database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print row[0], row[1], "$"+str(row[2])` would be the simplest way, closest to what you have now.

Answer (score 9):

```
print "{0} {1} ${2}".format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use string formatting while printing:

```
print '%s %s $%s' % (row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Most other solutions (namely: Ashwini Chaudhary's, Roman Bodnarchuk's and Junuxx's) are ok, but I would like to add two more:

```py
print row[0], row[1], '$%s' % row[2]
```

and

```
print row[0], row[1], '${}'.format(row[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you got more rows:

```
l = [str(r) for r in row]
l[-1] = "$%s" % l[-1]
print " ".join(l)
```